# Assign value to indices of nested lists stored as strings in R

Tags: r, eval

I have a dataframe of nested list indices, which have been stored as strings. To give a simplified example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("lst$x$y$a", "lst$x$y$b"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

These are then coordinates for the following list:

```
lst <- list(x=list(y=list(a="foo",b="bar",c="")))
```

I'd like replace values or assign new values to these elements using the indices in `df1`.

One attempt was

```
do.call(`<-`, list(eval(parse(text = df1[1,1])), "somethingelse"))
```

but this doesn't seem tow work. Instead it assigns `"something"` to `foo`.

I'm not too happy with using `eval(parse(text=))` (maintaining code will become a nightmare), but recognise I may have little choice.

Any tips welcome.

Comment: Can you be more clear with your expected results or desired output? In addition, are the number of hierarchies / levels consistent?

Comment: How did you get to this point? Where did `df1` come from? If you have code storied as strings, you're going to have to parse it at some point. If you want to allow any arbitrary R syntax, using the R parser makes sense (but is potentially "dangerous" as arbitrary code could be run). If you just got a bunch of keys separated by dollar signs, you could possibly make a safer version.

Comment: @MrFlick. I do agree, storing code in strings is far from ideal. The problem is that I'm working with a package that extracts to nested lists and for the purpose of oversight and editing outside R, these indices will have to be stored in CSV files. I'll reevaluate my options for this, but for now this method will have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider 3 situations:

**Case 1**

```
do.call(`<-`, list("lst$x$y$a", "somethingelse"))
```

This will create a new variable named `lst$x$y$a` in your workspace, so the following two commands will call different objects. (The former is the object you store in `lst`, and the latter is the new variable. You need to call it with backticks because its name will confuse R.)

```
> lst$x$y$a   # [1] "foo"
> `lst$x$y$a` # [1] "somethingelse"
```

---

**Case 2**

```
do.call(`<-`, list(parse(text = "lst$x$y$a"), "somethingelse"))
```

You mostly get what you expect with this one but an error still occurs:

> invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

Let's check:

```
> parse(text = "lst$x$y$a")  # expression(lst$x$y$a)
```

It belongs to the class `expression`, and the operator `<-` seems not to accept this class to the left-hand side.

---

**Case 3**

This one will achieve what you want:

```
do.call(`<-`, list(parse(text = "lst$x$y$a")[[1]], "somethingelse"))
```

If put `[[1]]` behind an `expression` object, a `call` object will be extracted and take effect in the operator `<-`.

```
> lst

# $x
# $x$y
# $x$y$a
# [1] "somethingelse"
# 
# $x$y$b
# [1] "bar"
# 
# $x$y$c
# [1] ""
```

Comment: Amazing many thanks! Would you perhaps have a resource where I can find more on this? I'm curious why `[[1]]` extracts the call `call` object.

Comment: @Svencken This is mentioned in `?expression`. You can see more details about the expression in it.

Comment: Many thanks for that. Keen to know more about how R works under the hood